# How to pass value from a form control via ajax to node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am new to jquery/node.js world. So, trying some basic stuff but getting stuck. Checked the questions but not able to get hold of a right approach.

So, here posting my code to understand what is wrong here:

I am using the express framework with view template engine build using ejs.

This is the script I have written in index.ejs

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button1").click(function() {
            var obj = $('#text1').val();
            $.post("/localhost:3000/",{val: obj}, function(restxt, status, xhr) {
                  if (status=="success") {
                    alert("External content loaded successfully");
                    //code
                  }
                  if (status=="error") {
                     alert(xhr.status + xhr.statusText);
                     //code
                  }                                        
              })
          })
      });  
</script>
```

And on index.js that render the html from ejs, I have written the following:

```
  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {     
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    if (req.form("val")!='') {
        console.log("we got some data: " + req.form("val"));
        res.send("ack");
    } else {
        console.log("still no data");
    }
 });
```

Thanks,

Nishith

Comment: You need a different route handler that will handle post requests as right now your route handles only get requests

Answer (score 0):

Add following under your router.get(...);

```
router.post('/', function(req,res,next){
    var val = req.body.val;
    res.send('got val');
});
```

Comment: I added it but still not getting logged. Is it that url in index.ejs which needs to be called should be different?

Comment: well yes you only need '/' or 'localhost:3000' without the first slash
and remove the if(req.form.... it's useless :) you have already res.render(.. you can't do res.send('ack'); after that it will cause error